# Can't upload data to firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following the [instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) to test firebase realtime database, but can't see any data on the console after saving data(running initialize() and saveData() methods below). 
And the log didn't show any error. 
What's the problem?

```
public static void initialize() {
        // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(keyPath);
            // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://myprojectId.firebaseio.com")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static void saveData() {
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("test");

        DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("vocabularies");

        Map<String, Vocabulary> vocabularies = new HashMap<>();

        Vocabulary v1 = new Vocabulary();
        v1.setWord("hello");
        v1.setDefinition("hello definition");
        v1.setTranslation("hello translation");

        Vocabulary v2 = new Vocabulary();
        v2.setWord("world");
        v2.setDefinition("world definition");
        v2.setTranslation("world translation");

        vocabularies.put("hello", v1);
        vocabularies.put("world", v2);

        usersRef.setValueAsync(vocabularies);
        }
```

Comment: The functionality you're showing is part of the Admin SDK, not Android. I see this is tagged with Android, so if you're trying to use this in an Android app, Alex is correct that the function doesn't exist. If you're trying to use this server-side, Louise is correct that the program exits before the work is done and you'll need to include some functionality to keep the thread alive until the work is complete.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) class, there is no `setValueAsync()` method. The only method that can help you set a value directly on a reference is `setValue()` method.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

Asked help from an experienced engineer, it's because the saving data task is running in a new thread and it's terminated before the data is uploaded when the main thread completes. To verify the explanation, I simply add

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

after saveData() in the main method. It succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused because I didn't enable the Token Service API for the project at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/securetoken.googleapis.com/overview?project= ***insert your project name here***